# Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS problem

Tags: mount

I have one drive which can be accessed from `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` and `Windows 8.1`. Lets call it Drive D.

When I shutdown `Windows 8.1` and start `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`, I'll not be able to mount Drive D. But when I restart `Windows 8.1` and select `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` to boot, then after booting, Drive D mounts.

Is there any bug in Windows/Ubuntu, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by [Fast Startup](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-or-enable-fast-startup-in-windows-8-1/) . (Follow the link and then you can read something brief.)

In Windows 8, Fast Startup is something like hibernating. The System logs out, then it saves something from your RAM to the disk. In this process, the NTFS Volume is marked as 'unclean' so Ubuntu rejects to mount it. But never try force mounting since this may cause data loss.

You should follow these steps to disable Fast Startup: (Most copied, ha)

- Open the Start Screen
- Search For "po bu". Click 'Change what the power buttons do'.
- Click on the 'Change settings that are currently unavailable' link to make the Shutdown options available.
- Untick the Turn on fast startup (enabled) option.